# Asyncio getting different outputs

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

In the first example I am getting `output` I expect here to be, but I can't say same about second example. Technically, in both example I have 3 `tasks` (Just in second example, I am scheduling 2 `coros` execution from `main coro`) isn't it ? In second example, why `Event loop` does not resume `main() coro` in the same fashion as in first example ?

**Example 1:**

```py
import time
import asyncio

async def coro1():
    while True:
        print('coro1()')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # yield ! Give control back to event loop, to start/resume another task !

async def coro2():
    while True:
        print('coro2()')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # yield ! Give control back to event loop, to start/resume another task !

async def main():
    while True:
        print('main()')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # yield ! Give control back to event loop, to start/resume another task ! 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    main_task = loop.create_task(main())

    task1 = loop.create_task(coro1()) # Schedule execution of coro !
    task2 = loop.create_task(coro2()) # # Schedule execution of coro !
    
    loop.run_until_complete(main_task)

    loop.close()
```

**Example 1 Output:**

```bash
main()
coro1()
coro2()
main()
coro1()
coro2()
main()
coro1()
coro2()
```

**Example 2:**

```py
import time
import asyncio

async def coro1():
    while True:
        print('coro1()')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # yield ! Give control back to event loop, to start/resume another task !

async def coro2():
    while True:
        print('coro2()')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # yield ! Give control back to event loop, to start/resume another task !

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(coro1()) # Schedule execution of coro from main !
    task2 = loop.create_task(coro2()) # Schedule execution of coro from main !
    while True:
        print('main()')
        await task1 # yield ! Give control back to event loop, to start/resume another task ! 
        await task2 # yield ! Give control back to event loop, to start/resume another task ! 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    main_task = loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(main_task)

    loop.close()
```

**Example 2 output:**

```bash
main()
coro1()
coro2()
coro1()
coro2()
coro1()
coro2()
```

Comment: It is hard to explain why. May be you can read more examples about asyncio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your tasks ever *complete*, they'll all continue endlessly. In the first case, each task in itself only `await`s `asyncio.sleep`, which does complete; the code then continues with the next loop iteration.

In your second case, the `main` task `await`s the completion of the `coro1()` task, before it will continue with its loop. Since `coro1` never completes, it is indefinitely stuck at the `await task1` line.